# Convert Pandas DF 'QQ YY' format to a start and end date in new columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My company collects projected procurement windows in a 'qq yy' format. IE 'Q1 26'. I'd like to transform the date to two new columns titled 'Procurement Start' and ' Procurement End' to a mm/dd/yy format using fiscal year starting on October 1st.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Projected Date':['Q1 26', 'Q2 26', 'Q3 26', 'Q4 26']})
```

I would expect the output to look like this:

| Projected Date | Procurement Start Date | Procurement End Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Q1 26 | 10/01/25 | 12/31/25 |
| Q2 26 | 01/01/26 | 3/31/26 |
| Q3 26 | 04/01/26 | 06/30/26 |
| Q4 26 | 07/01/26 | 9/30/26 |

It doesn't seem that the qq yy format is accepted in pd.to_datetime. I'm also getting hung up on formatting the first quarter to be October.

Answer (score 1):

**Code**

```
s = pd.to_datetime(
    df['Projected Date'].str.split(' ').pipe(lambda x: x.str[1] + x.str[0])
)

fmt = '%m/%d/%y'
df['Procurement Start Date'] = s.sub(pd.DateOffset(months=3)).dt.strftime(fmt)
df['Procurement End Date'] = s.sub(pd.DateOffset(days=1)).dt.strftime(fmt)
```

df:

```
  Projected Date Procurement Start Date Procurement End Date
0          Q1 26               10/01/25             12/31/25
1          Q2 26               01/01/26             03/31/26
2          Q3 26               04/01/26             06/30/26
3          Q4 26               07/01/26             09/30/26
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`PeriodIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.html) subtracting one quarter and [`start_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.start_time.html)/[`end_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.PeriodIndex.end_time.html)

```
idx = pd.PeriodIndex(df['Projected Date'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex=True),
                     freq='Q')-1

df['Procurement Start Date'] = idx.start_time.normalize()
df['Procurement End Date'] = idx.end_time.normalize()
```

Output:

```
  Projected Date Procurement Start Date Procurement End Date
0          Q1 26             2025-10-01           2025-12-31
1          Q2 26             2026-01-01           2026-03-31
2          Q3 26             2026-04-01           2026-06-30
3          Q4 26             2026-07-01           2026-09-30
```

To convert to PeriodIndex you first need a YY-Qn string.

Intermediate:

```
df['Projected Date'].str.replace(r'(Q\d) (\d+)', r'\2-\1', regex=True)

0    26-Q1
1    26-Q2
2    26-Q3
3    26-Q4
Name: Projected Date, dtype: object
```